# Mix topsoil with compost for vegetable garden

Tags: vegetables, compost, topsoil

I'm trying to convert my backyard into a vegetable garden. I am first removing the sod. Is it OK to replace the matter with a 50/50 blend of topsoil and compost? Topsoil costs half of that of compost. The topsoil I am referring to is what can be bought in Lowe's/Home Depot. The compost comes in one bag and is a compost and manure mix.

Comment: You can almost certainly get better quality soil and compost delivered by the truckload for less money than buying bags at home centers that have been shipped all over the country. Certainly most of the alleged compost from there is uncomposted wood chunks mixed with a nominal quantity of composted manure, in my dissatisfied experience. Run a sample bag through a 1/4" mesh screen and see what comes out.

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of wood chunks in the compost.

Comment: If you are getting a load stuff delivered, consider also getting woodchips for paths (which will, over time, convert into a compost which you can then move into the beds they are right next to).   Woodchips also make an excellent mulch - provided they are either aged, or you are planting stuff where most of the roots are not in the top inch or so of soil.